# Want to drop duplicate based on one column but want to keep first two rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, drop-duplicates

Hi I am droping duplicate from dataframe based on one column i.e "ID", Till now i am droping the duplicate and keeping the first occurence but I want to keep the first(top) two occurrence instead of only one. So I can compare the values of first two rows of another column "similarity_score".

`data_2 = data.sort_values('similarity_score' , ascending = False)`

`data_2.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID'], keep='first').reset_index()`

Answer (score 0):

Let us `sort` the values then do `groupby + head`

```
data.sort_values('similarity', ascending=False).groupby('ID').head(2)
```

Alternatively, you can use `groupby + nlargest` which will also give you the desired result:

```
data.groupby('ID')['similarity'].nlargest(2).droplevel(1)
```